# "locator", "slider", "gauges" - should they be combined into "controls"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I am honored to be in the company of such productive, curious, and creative people like you, now almost for couple of months.

I noticed that tag policy on Mathematica SE site is to keep the tag structure simple, and therefore number of tags low (this is my understanding from observation, I may be wrong).

Would than tags [locator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locator), [slider](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slider), [gauges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauges) be amalgamated into the tag [controls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controls)?

If, yes, please somebody do something about it (I have too low reputation for that).

Comment: There is a related question: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/possible-tag-merge-controls-gui-elements?rq=1

Answer (score 16):

Yes, they all belong to "controls".

Comment: I would favour something more specific like "ui-controls" or "dynamic-controls"

Comment: Voted for this, with the condition that the tag name should be more specific (what Verbeia suggested).

Answer (score 6):

I don't mind merging `locator` and `slider` into something relating to controls. I do think that gauges shouldn't be though, since they are used more for "output" than "input".

Answer (score 0):

No, they should remain separate tags.